# Fullcalendar 6 - rendering days and week days as links by default

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

It seems that days and weekdays are rendered as links by default (e.g. `<a>{dayContent}</a>`). Any way to disable/control this and have them rendered as `<div>` or `<span>` for example?

Things I tried:

- dayCellContent: only changes the content, but it's still wrapped by `<a>`
- navLinks = false (default value), indeed clicking on days doesn't change the view (no navigation) but days are still rendered as links

In case it matters, I'm using `@fullcalendar/react`

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/day-header-render-hooks

Comment: @ADyson `dayHeaderContent` seems to be similar to `dayCellContent` except it affects the headers only - I can change the content with it but that content is still wrapped by `<a>`. I believe if `navLinks=false` the `<a>` should not be used at all, no?

Comment: Why do you believe that? Evidently that isn't the case, based on what we can observe. If you think that's a bug, raise a bug with fullCalendar but I don't see why it would be a bug. Is the presence of the `<a>` causing you a problem? If there's no `href` then it won't appear like a link in the display (demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/eYjromb) . An anchor tag is more than just for hyperlinks, potentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `dayHeaderDidMount` from the Day Header Render Hooks feature, which gives you full control to set the inner content of the table cell however you like.

Here's a trivial example (using vanilla JS, since I'm not familiar with React, but the basic principle is the same):

```
dayHeaderDidMount: function (arg) {
  arg.el.innerHTML = arg.text;
},
```

Live demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/LYMmppx

Documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/day-header-render-hooks

Comment: Thank you @ADyson! I'm not sure how I could do that with React but I ended up going around it by adjusting the CSS with "a:not([href])".

I still believe it would be more intuitive to not use `<a>` at all if there's actually no links (and as such, no `hrefs`).  It seems to be there just as a default for when navLinks=true.

I understand this is minor thing though and easily "workaroundable", so all good to me.

Comment: `I'm not sure how I could do that with React` ...it should be identical apart from the syntax to declare the option in your fullcalendar options. e.g. dayHeaderDidMount={this.handleDayHeaderDidMount}` and then have a function of that name somewhere. Similar to the examples in the "Callbacks" section in https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react

Comment: `I still believe it would be more intuitive to not use <a> at all if there's actually no links (and as such, no hrefs)`...it depends if they are used as an anchor for navigation or other things at some point by fullCalendar, I guess. Or it could just be an oversight by the fullCalendar developers perhaps, I don't know. Either way, you can use code like I've shown to completely remove it. P.S. I don't know why an anchor tag in HTML ended up being used for hyperlinks as well, it seems to be two different functionalities combined into one tag. There's prob some historical accidental reason!